# Initial position for SVG draggable using Jquery-svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to make parts of this SVG draggable and it works, but the initial click starts from 0,0 offset and I can't seem to get it to work from the original offset. After the initial click it's fine.

http://aubergene.com/roller-derby-track/index3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your jQuery to the latest version, it might have a bit of a conflict with jQuery UI.

Latest builds of both work great.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/aestj/1/